# Displaying Message After Redirecting from angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If a user tries to access a page that he is not authorised to I redirect him to the home page.

I would like to show a message why he is redirected to the home page with out passing an url parameter.

What's the "best" way to do that in angular 1.5 ? globalscope? pubsub?

Answer (score 0):

You could use non-url parameters, described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls

State config:

```
.state('contacts', {
    url: "/contacts",
    params: {
        param1: null
    }
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})
```

ui-sref:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({param1: value1})">View Contacts</a>
```

$state.go:

```
$state.go('contacts', {param1: value1})
```

You can access the parameter via `$stateParams` the same way if it was a url parameter.